# Метод say в js. помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию-конструктор Animal. Она должна создавать объекты со свойствами type и phrase и записывать в них значения, которые функция принимает на вход. Также у сконструированных объектов должен быть метод `say`. Он выводит в консоль текст по шаблону: <животное> says <что оно говорит>.

```
    function Animal(type, phrase) {
  // добавьте type и phrase в this
  this.type = type;
  this.phrase = phrase;
}

const fox = new Animal('fox', 'woopwoopwoop');
const tRex = new Animal('T-rex', 'ЯAWR');

fox.say(); // fox says woopwoopwoop
tRex.say(); // T-rex says ЯAWR

// метод можно добавить в прототип
Animal.prototype.say = function () {
  console.log(/* как сконструировать нужную фразу? */);
};
```

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать внимательно: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods Там есть все нужные объяснения. Если потом что-то будет неясно или не получится написать код, задайте более конкретные вопросы.

Comment: а зачем вы добавляете функу `say`в прототипе, вам чтото помешало добавить ее в самой функции конструкторе ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, а почему бы ее не в прототип добавлять?

Comment: Подсказка: Напишите `console.log( this )`

Comment: @Grundy я думаю что для новичка будет более понятно если все будет в одном месте описано

Answer (score 0):

```js
Animal.prototype.say = function() {
  console.log(`${this.type} says ${this.phrase}`);
};
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
function Animal(type, phrase) {

    this.type = type;
    this.phrase = phrase;
    this.say = function() {
        console.log(`${this.type} says ${this.phrase}`);
    };
}

const fox = new Animal('fox', 'woopwoopwoop');  
const tRex = new Animal('T-rex', 'ЯAWR');

fox.say();  
tRex.say();
```